# AWS Kubernetes RDS connection

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-rds

I'm having some trouble with my AWS Kubernetes instance.

I'm trying to get my django instances to connect to the RDS service via the DB endpoint.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': os.environ['NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['USER'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': os.environ['HOST'],
        'PORT': os.environ['PORT']
    }
}
```

The host string would resemble this service.key.region.rds.amazonaws.com and is being passed to the container via env in the deploy.yml

```
containers:
  - name: service
    env:
      - name: HOST
        value: service.key.region.rds.amazonaws.com
```

This set up works locally in kubernetes but not when I put it in the cluster I have on AWS. It returns the following error instead:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name
```

Any suggestions or am I missing something in how AWS likes handling things?

Comment: Are you using EKS?

Comment: Is there any chance your manage.py file is reading the wrong settings file? Asking because I saw [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573313/docker-compose-with-django-could-not-translate-host-name-db-to-address-name-o) that feels possibly related to your issue, despite being about Docker.

Comment: No rolling my own with kubeadm, 1 master 1 node. Attempting to learn the hard-ish way.

Comment: Is your AWS deployment in the same VPC as your RDS now?

Comment: @ingernet I just double checked my settings files and by base.py doesn't hold any DB configs. I changed some things and rebuilt the image just to be sure and I still get the same error. Good thought though, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @the4thv ya they clusters are in the same VPC as the RDS

Comment: Never thought to check that. I can psql into the RDS service with no issue. Hmm might be a django issue...

Comment: I would still guess it's more Kubernetes, as it has it's own DNS service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your AWS deployment is now in the same VPC as your RDS, then you will need to change your host to use the private IP.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but where do I find the private ip of the RDS, the closest I can find in the RDS dashboard is the endpoint.

Comment: OK, before I decide this is absolutely wrong, try pinging the RDS end point to get the private IP address. Then use that in your deployment.

Comment: Awesome! I think that it's related to Kubernetes internal routing: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Comment: Thanks for the help and the link. Much appreciated

Comment: what if you're in a different VPC, different account, different region?